# Why isn't SQL Endpoints enabled in Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I want to create an SQL Endpoint as per the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/admin/sql-endpoints

However this option does not appear in the databricks assets drop down:

[image]

Why not and how can I enable SQL Endpoints in my Azure Databricks instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Requirements**

- Your Azure Databricks account must be on the Premium plan.
- Launch a workspace. You can use an existing workspace or create a new one
- You must be an Azure Databricks admin. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/get-started/admin-onboarding#requirements)

Comment: Thanks turns out we were on Standard plan.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for that:

- (most probable) administrators didn't give you access to Databricks SQL - they need to follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/admin/users-groups#--grant-a-user-access-to-databricks-sql) to enable it for users or groups.
- your workspace is not on Premium plan ([requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/get-started/admin-onboarding#requirements) in docs)